# CSS: ellipsis with right add-on that should always be visible

Tags: css, css-float

I have 3 objects in a line - `Text`, `Icon` and `Date`.

First goes `Text`, then goes `Icon` (stuck to the end of the `Text`). And the `Date` is stuck to the right side of the line.

When `Text` is too long, I want it to be shortened with ellipsis, but the `Icon` should always remain visible (not become shortened with `Text`).

With the code below I made it almost working, but the Icon is stuck to the right.

But I need it to be stuck to the `Text`. Please see the code below or [this JsFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/z2gwv/).

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="date">right</div>
    <div class="icon">[icon]</div>
    <div class="text">Long text long text long text long text</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="date">right</div>
    <div class="icon">[icon]</div>
    <div class="text">Short text</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 200px;
}

.text, .date, .icon {
    padding-right: 5px;
}

.text {
    text-align:left;
    display: block;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.date {
    float: right;
}

.icon {
    float: right;
}
```

**UPDATE**: width of all fields may vary.

Comment: I see your `.wrapper` is fixed-width. Can you do that to your `.date` and `.icon`?

Comment: to .icon - yes, to .date - no

Comment: If it's still important I remembered that in real app even the width of .icon is not static. There can be multiple icons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work on my Chrome and Opera Presto; Firefox works in some situation, but has serious problem in other situation that makes it impractical. Plus its structure might be too complicated.

I post it here anyway, in case it inspire someone :)
(By OP's request, I added a JS-involved solution at the end, which works in Firefox too)

### Solution:

[**jsfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Jj6T2/)

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="date">right</div>
    <div class="sub-wrapper">
        <div class="final-wrapper">
            <div class="icon">[icon]</div>
            <div class="text">text</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.wrapper {
    width:200px;
}
div.date, div.icon, div.text {
    padding-right:5px;
}
div.date, div.icon {
    float:right;
}
div.sub-wrapper, div.final-wrapper, div.text {
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
div.sub-wrapper {
    text-align:left;
}
div.final-wrapper {
    display:inline-block;
    max-width:100%;
}
```

Basically this is a recursive use of "One thing float right, then the other thing take the rest space", plus a `.final-wrapper` so the icons can be left-aligned.

### Problem in Firefox:

Since `.final-wrapper` is `display:inline-block`, and `.icon` is `float`, Firefox will only calculate the width long enough to hold `.text` (unless `.icon` is longer), so:
if the length of `.text` can fit `.icon`, `.icon` will stay in, and ellipsis will show up even though there seem to have enough space;
if `.icon` is longer than `.text`, `.icon` will take the whole place, and `.text` will be pushed to the next line, overflowing wrappers (and `overflow:hidden` will not work unless you explicitly specify a `height`).

---

### Solution with JS:

In conjunction with the above structure, adding a small piece of JS can make the solution Firefox friendly:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){
    var texts=document.querySelectorAll(".final-wrapper > .icon + .text");
    [].forEach.call(texts,function(text){
        var icon=text.previousSibling;
        while(!icon.classList || !icon.classList.contains("icon")){
            icon=icon.previousSibling;
        }
        var box=icon.getBoundingClientRect();
        text.style.marginRight=(box.width+5)+"px";
    });
});
```

[**jsfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Jj6T2/1/)

It's base on the assumption that `.icon` will be at a fixed width once its rendered.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I want except the problem with Firefox.

Comment: @Bandolero If your `.icon` is fixed-width this may still be possible. If the deadline is near I would go for a JS solution.

Comment: The "icon" can be two types - a font-awesome icon and a label [new]. So technically speaking each of them is fixed-width, but for each particular row there can be none of them (min), and there can be two icons and one label (max). Can you please show me a direction with the JS solution, perhaps in separate answer?

Comment: @Bandolero It's actually not very complicated: http://jsfiddle.net/Jj6T2/1/ but you'll have to make sure that `.text` have enough space to at least show the first character and the ellipsis.

Comment: Thank you very much! I "accepted" your answer, please add this solution to the answer for others could find it easier.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work in Safari - http://snag.gy/AuAvk.jpg. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: @Bandolero I was busy with my work so sorry for a late response, but it's quite difficult to debug with just a screenshot...anyway, since JS is already involved, would you like to see if this works: http://jsfiddle.net/Jj6T2/2/ ?